# How do you list all processes on the command line in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a command equivalent to 'ps' on Unix that can list all processes on a Windows machine?

Comment: This [Starting and Stopping process in Windows from command Line](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/09/starting-and-stopping-process-in.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Working with cmd.exe:

> [`tasklist`](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)

If you have [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.2):

> [`get-process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.2)

Via WMI:

> wmic process

(you can query remote machines as well with `/node:ComputerOrIP`, and there are a LOT more ways to customize this command: [link](https://quux.wiki.zoho.com/WMIC-Snippets.html#Processes))

Comment: you might want to pipe it to the clipboard then paste into notepad:
    c:\>tasklist | clip

Comment: Specifically you could try >tasklist /FI "SERVICES eq wampapache"

Comment: If I list tasks with tasklist, how do I then end a task from command prompt?

Comment: If you use Powershell, it's really convenient to pipe it to Out-Gridview, like this:  "Get-Process | Out-GridView"

Comment: Or just pipe it directly into a text file:  C:>tasklist > C:\myProcesses.txt

Comment: "The WMI command-line (WMIC) utility is deprecated as of Windows 10"  Please use Get-WmiObject or tothers.

Answer (score 92):

There is a tool called [Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line tool (wmic.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784189%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

You can call `wmic process list` to see all processes.

Comment: I found this s.o. thread while trying to solve the same problem, and wanted to point out that wmic worked well for me.  With wmic you can choose the most appropriate output for parsing, using /format:csv or /format:rawout.  Beware:  wmic does *not* implement csv format correctly (fields are *never* quoted, even if they contain embedded quotes or commas), so I was forced to use xml.

Comment: @JimN - /format:rawxml and not /format:rawout

Comment: Can you filter any process using wmic ?

Comment: If you need to find the command line that launched the process this is the answer

Comment: To **reduce the number of columns** to print: `wmic process get ProcessId,Description,ParentProcessId,ReadOperationCount,WriteOperationCount`, and as @ShaneGannon suggested, you might query the `ParentProcessId` to find child processes, e.g.: https://justpaste.it/6kjou

Answer (score 31):

I wanted to mention that WMIC (pam's entry) can do a *lot* more. Have a look at my WMIC snippets page, which is a cheatsheet showing many of the common ways to use WMIC (with sample output shown) [here](http://quux.wiki.zoho.com/WMIC-Snippets.html)

Comment: A simplified example (**less columns**): `wmic process get ProcessId,Description,ParentProcessId,ReadOperationCount,WriteOperationCount`

Comment: Your page about WMIC and WMIC+PS is quite useful.

Answer (score 22):

1. Tasklist
2. WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid

or

```
 WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt path win32_process get Caption,Processid,Commandline
```

Answer (score 21):

I tried on Windows 7. The command is: `TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq application_name"`

Eg: `c:\>TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe"`

To show all process with port details:

```
c:\> TASKLIST
```

Also to kill the process you can use `c:\> pskill or tskill processname`

Eg: `c:\> tskill notepad`

Comment: `TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"` returns one whole line as output. Is there anyway to get just the PID itself?

Comment: for a more human-memorable command, `taskkill` is synonymous to `tskill`

Comment: On 8.1, there is no `tskill` only `taskkill`, and `pskill` is provided by SysInternals but not Windows. (@KiritoBepsibane)

Answer (score 12):

tasklist or [pslist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) from sysinternals. Also, get-process is amazing from [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx).

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx), it has the 'ps' command (it is aliased to Get-Process)

Comment: This alias is part of a long list of convenient aliases set by default, which makes life easier for people used to Unix commands.
One can get such list (into a file for later reference) with `Get-Alias > ps_alias.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

To kill a process use:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM processname.exe
```

For example:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM firefox.exe
```

Comment: This isn't a good answer. The question is how to list processes, not how to kill them.

Answer (score 2):

If you running windows XP try using the 'tasklist' command. I tried it out with Vista and it seems to also work.

Answer (score 2):

open windows command prompt

```
C:\>tasklist                       // list all the tasks


C:\>Taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F     // Kill task by name
```

or

```
C:\>Taskkill /PID 26356 /F           // kill task by PId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to see all the processes in windows machine

**tasklist /svc**

Comment: Can  you filter any process using tasklist with pipe or another way ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Yes you can: `tasklist|findstr "firefox.exe"`. If this returns an `errorlevel` of 1 the process was found in the list of processes.

Comment: @mrt: `findstr` doesn't need quotes around the needle unless it contains space or special character like & although `find` does, and both of them return 1 for NOT found (0 for found).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Of course you are right, but in my opinion it's a good habit to put strings into quotes. This keeps me from accidently leave them out when they are needed. Also, it makes the statement easier to read since it's instantly obvious what the search term is.

Answer (score 1):

Using WMI and Powershell you can do:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Process
```

Then you can filter properties using `Select-Object` and show in GUI using `Out-GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a msproject ( c source code) , archive is available at :
[lsproc.zip project archive](http://bremardt.free.fr/c/lsproc.zip)

and exe file:
[lsproc.exe binary](http://bremardt.free.fr/c/lsproc.exe)

this is a command line tool
output:

```
lsproc 
Thierry Bremard
t.bremard@gmail.com
list binary files and driver with their local path on disks
most of code retreived from msdn site
--------------------

Process ID: 0
--------------------

Process ID: 4
<unknown>  (PID: 4)
<unknown>
    PageFaultCount             : 0x00002E4B
    PeakWorkingSetSize         : 0x00419000
    WorkingSetSize (Mem usage) : 0x0003A000 (232 ko)
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage    : 0x00000000
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage        : 0x00000000
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage : 0x00000000
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage     : 0x00000000
    PagefileUsage              : 0x00000000
    PeakPagefileUsage          : 0x00000000
--------------------

Process ID: 764
smss.exe  (PID: 764)
\SystemRoot\System32\smss.exe
    PageFaultCount             : 0x000000D6
    PeakWorkingSetSize         : 0x00082000
    WorkingSetSize (Mem usage) : 0x0006C000 (432 ko)
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage    : 0x00006C34
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage        : 0x00001854
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage : 0x000004D8
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage     : 0x00000280
    PagefileUsage              : 0x0002C000
    PeakPagefileUsage          : 0x00030000
--------------------

Process ID: 816
--------------------

Process ID: 844
winlogon.exe  (PID: 844)
\??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe
    PageFaultCount             : 0x0000261D
    PeakWorkingSetSize         : 0x00B58000
    WorkingSetSize (Mem usage) : 0x0029B000 (2668 ko)
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage    : 0x0001B054
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage        : 0x000185A4
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage : 0x0000C988
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage     : 0x0000B6A0
    PagefileUsage              : 0x005EC000
    PeakPagefileUsage          : 0x006C6000
--------------------

...
    PeakPagefileUsage          : 0x03277000
--------------------

Process ID: 2712
lsproc.exe  (PID: 2712)
C:\Documents and Settings\LoginX\Bureau\lsproc.exe
    PageFaultCount             : 0x000000EC
    PeakWorkingSetSize         : 0x000F1000
    WorkingSetSize (Mem usage) : 0x000E4000 (912 ko)
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage    : 0x000032B4
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage        : 0x000032B4
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage : 0x00000400
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage     : 0x00000398
    PagefileUsage              : 0x00042000
    PeakPagefileUsage          : 0x0005C000
There are 131 drivers:
--------------------
   1: ntkrnlpa.exe
\WINDOWS\system32\ntkrnlpa.exe
--------------------
   2: hal.dll
\WINDOWS\system32\hal.dll
--------------------
   3: KDCOM.DLL
\WINDOWS\system32\KDCOM.DLL
--------------------
   4: BOOTVID.dll
\WINDOWS\system32\BOOTVID.dll


...


--------------------
 129: HTTP.sys
\SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\HTTP.sys
--------------------
 130: hiber_WMILIB.SYS
\SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\hiber_WMILIB.SYS
--------------------
 131: ntdll.dll
\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll



--------------
```

Comment: file not found, mister

Answer (score 0):

**For more process info**

running in cmd,handle is the process id:

```
wmic.exe path Win32_Process where handle='22792' get Commandline /format:list
```

result:

```
/path/to/app.exe [args specified goes here]
```

Answer (score -2):

Hello if you want to list running process ID's on a Windows machine then open a `cmd` screen and type:

```
netstat -aon | more
```

use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to scroll.

Comment: That only gives processes that are accessing the network, which is NOT all processes.